# C++ istream with lex

Tags: c++, parsing, lex, lexer

I have a working grammar (written in lex and bison) that parses polynomial expressions.  It is like your standard, text-book calculator-like syntax.  Here is a very simplified version of the grammar:

```
Expr
: DOUBLE        {$$ = newConstExpr($1);}
| Expr '+' Expr {$$ = newBinaryExpr('+', $1, $2);}
| Expr '*' Expr {$$ = NewBinaryExpr('*', $1, $2);}
| '(' Expr ')'  {$$ = $2;}
;
```

My problem is that Lex uses a FILE* for yyin, and I need to parse input from a C++ istream. I know that flex++ can generate the FlexLexer class (which can take an istream in its constructo), but it is difficult to get it to mesh with Bison, and even the author himself claims (in the comments in the generated lexer file) that it is buggy.

So I am wondering if anyone knows a good way to use a flex scanner and bison parser with a C++ istream object as the input instead of a FILE*.

Comment: Have you read the [example](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#A-Complete-C_002b_002b-Example) in the bison manual?  Or the [other](http://idlebox.net/2007/flex-bison-cpp-example/) [examples](http://www.thebinaryidiot.com/archives/2010/03/06/flex-bison-cpp-example/) google found?

Comment: I have seen some of these, and found them to not be helpful.  One of these examples looks promising, though.  I will look into it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can get input into lex however you want by definining a custom `YY_INPUT` macro.

For a real-world example, take a look at my:

http://www.kylheku.com/cgit/txr/tree/parser.l

Here, I redirect the `flex` scanner to work with special stream objects which are part of a dynamic object library. Like `iostream`s, these are not `FILE *`.

This allows me to do things like lexically analyze the command line when the program is run with `-c <script text>`.

(As an aside, the scanner works with 8 bit bytes. This is why the `YY_INPUT` macro uses my `get_byte` function. When the `yyin_stream` is a string stream, the `get_byte` implementation will actually put out the UTF-8 encoding bytes corresponding to the Unicode chars inside the string, so multiple `get_byte` calls may be necessary before the stream advances to the  next character of the string. Over a file stream, `get_byte` just gets the byte from the underlying OS stream.)

Comment: Note carefully that `YY_INPUT` deliberately stops reading and returns a partially filled buffer when it sees a newline. This is important if the underlying stream is ever interactive. If `YY_INPUT` simply keeps reading characters until it fills the buffer, it will undo the effect of an interactive unbuffered or line-buffered stream underneath, making it appear buffered! If you ever want instant character-at-a-time responsiveness from lex, you will also have to rewrite YY_INPUT not to buffer lines (in addition to making arrangements for that style of input from your underlying system).

Answer (score 1):

This is a working example of a custom YY_INPUT macro to read from an interactive istream.

```
%{
// Place this code in istr.l and run with:
// $ flex istr.l && c++ istr.cpp && ./a.out
// $ flex istr.l && c++ istr.cpp && ./a.out 1a2b 123 abc
#include <iostream>

// The stream the lexer will read from.
// Declared as an extern
extern std::istream *lexer_ins_;

// Define YY_INPUT to get from lexer_ins_
// This definition mirrors the functionality of the default
// interactive YY_INPUT
#define YY_INPUT(buf, result, max_size)  \
  result = 0; \
  while (1) { \
    int c = lexer_ins_->get(); \
    if (lexer_ins_->eof()) { \
      break; \
    } \
    buf[result++] = c; \
    if (result == max_size || c == '\n') { \
      break; \
    } \
  }

%}

/* Turn on all the warnings, don't call yywrap. */
%option warn nodefault noyywrap
/* stdinit not required - since using streams. */
%option nostdinit
%option outfile="istr.cpp"

%%
      /* Example rules. */
[0-9] { std::cout << 'd'; }
\n    { std::cout << std::endl; }
.     { std::cout << '.'; }
<<EOF>> { yyterminate(); }
%%

//
// Example main. This could be in its own file.
//
#include <sstream>

// Define actual lexer stream 
std::istream *lexer_ins_;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  if (argc == 1) {
    // Use stdin
    lexer_ins_ = &std::cin;
    yylex();
  } else {
    // Use a string stream
    std::string data;
    for (int n = 1; n < argc; n++) {
      data.append(argv[n]);
      data.append("\n");
    }
    lexer_ins_ = new std::istringstream(data);
    yylex();
  }
}
```

This style of scanner - using C++ but generated in the C-style - works fine for me. You might also try the experimental Flex option `%option c++`. See "Generating C++ Scanners" in the Flex manual. There doesn't seem to be much information about integrating these scanners with a Bison parser.

Finally, in case reading from memory is sufficient for your use case, you might be able to avoid redefining YY_INPUT - see `yy_scan_buffer()` in the Flex manual.